# Is the limit finite?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find $r>0$ for which the following limit is finite

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}$$

I get inconclusiveness using the ratio test. The root test does not seem to help me. Does it converge to zero to for $r \in Z^+$?

Any ideas?

Comment: for what stands $k$ here?

Comment: The root and ratio tests are for *series* (where you sum infinitely many terms). Here you just have a single term. (Unless there is something you're not telling us. Where's that "$k$" coming from, for example?)

Comment: I am sorry, I completely mistated the question. Please see the corrected question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992252/is-the-limit-finite-corrected

Answer (score 2):

Divide the limit up and down by $n^r$ then
$$\lim_n \frac{1/n}{1+ (k/n)^r}.$$

The numerator tends to 0 always. Now $(k/n)^r$ tends to 0 if $r>0$, to the overall limit seems to tend to 0 no matter $r$ and $k$.

Comment: Sure, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n+\frac{k^r}{n^{r-1}}}$$