# Is the limit finite? (corrected)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I need to find $r>0$ for which the following limit is finite

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}$$

I get inconclusiveness using the ratio test. The root test does not seem to help me. Does it converge to zero to for $r \in \mathbb Z^+$?

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure about the $n^2$ on the top?

Comment: Yes, it is a $n^2$ on the top of sum.

Answer (score 4):

We first observe that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}\ge \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+n^r}=n^2\cdot\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}\to \infty.
$$
Therefore, for every $r\ge 0$, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}=\infty.
$$

Comment: I am a bit confused. Does that mean does not exist an $r>0$ for which the limit is finite?

Comment: This is indeed correct. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** rewrite this as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac1{1 + \left(\frac kn\right)^r}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $r\geq1$ the partial sums, counted to $n$ behave as $(1/n)$ and the longer ones are bigger, hence it diverges.